# Explanation of statements in paper required (pde, calculus, analysis)

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations

(I am reading a paper called *Shortening Complete Plane Curves* by Kai-Seng Chou & Xi-Ping Zhu. It is available at [Link](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/journal-of-differential-geometry/volume-50/issue-3/Shortening-complete-plane-curves/10.4310/jdg/1214424967.full). Page 476 is relevant)

Consider the partial differential equation on the domain $\mathbb{R}\times [0,T]$:
$$u_t - A(x,t)u_{xx} + \text{l.o.t} = f$$
where $$A(x,t) = \frac{(1-k_0(x)^2t)^2}{[(1-k_0(x)^2t)^2 + (k_{0_x}(x)t)^2]^2}$$
where $k_0(x)$ is the curvature of the curve $\gamma_0:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^2$.

Recall that a PDE is uniformly parabolic if there exist positive constants $a$ and $b$ such that the term in the front of the Laplacian sits between $a$ and $b$, i.e., $a \leq A(x,t) \leq b$.

Questions:

1. Why is it true that

> $A$ is bounded in $C^{k, \alpha}(\mathbb{R} \times [0,T])$ if $\gamma_0 \in C^{k+4, \alpha}(\mathbb{R})$?

Something to do with the fact that $k_0$ depends on $(\gamma_0)_{xx}$?

2. Why is it true that

> If we restrict $T$ so that, for example, $$T < \frac{1}{2}\inf_x \frac{1}{1+k_0^2(x)},$$
> then the PDE is uniformly parabolic.

I don't see where that comes from at all.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3):

1) Yes, if in $k_0$ there are derivatives of up to the second order, then $\frac{\partial} {\partial x}A(x,t)$ contains $k_0$ derivatives of order no more than three etc. Also it is infinitely differentiable with respect to $t$. The only thing to be checked here is that the denominator is bounded away from zero. But generally it does not hold. 
For example, if $k_0(x_0)\ne0\;$ and ${k_0}_x(x_0)=0\;$ then 
$$
A(x_0,t) = \frac{1}{(1-k_0(x_0)^2t)^2}\to\infty, \quad t\to k_0^{-2}(x_0).
$$
However, for small enough values of $t$ (as restricted in the question below),
$$
1-k_0(x_0)^2t \ge 1-\frac12\frac{k_0^2(x)}{1+k_0^2(x)}\ge\frac12,
$$
thus the denominator is bounded away from zero by $1/16$.

2) Put $C_1=\sup_x |k_{0}(x)|\;$, $C_2=\sup_x |k_{0_x}(x)|\;$. Then we have
$$
A(x,t)\ge 
\frac{\frac14}{\left(\frac14+C_2^2T^2\right)^2}=a,
$$
$$
A(x,t)\le \frac
{(1+C_1^2T)^2}{\frac1{16}}=b.
$$

Comment: Thanks Andrew. I'll just think about it a little before awarding it to you.

Comment: How did you get the $\frac{1}{4}$ in the denominator for inequality involving $a$? I get a term involving $C_1$ there.

Comment: Also, am I right that I should use the inequality for $T$ given in the paper to get rid of $T$ in $a$ and $b$ as it doesn't seem to make sense to keep it in that form.

Comment: @blackcat $1/4$ is from the estimate $1-k_0(x_0)^2t \ge\frac12$ above.
The maximal value of $T$ depend on $C_1$ but it is already taken into account in the condition $T < \frac{1}{2}\inf_x \frac{1}{1+k_0^2(x)}$. As for $T$ from this estimate it is just an explicitly pointed out length of time period (depending on $\gamma$) then the equation is guaranteed to be uniformly parabolic. The relevant thing here is perhaps that such an interval do exist and depends on a certain norm of $\gamma$ but not its exact value.

Comment: Thanks @Andrew but for the specfic inequality $A(x,t) \geq a$, the $1-k_0^2t$ is in the denominator of $A(x,t)$ so we can't substitute in the 1/2 (as then we'd get $A(x,t) \leq ..$.) But I think this can be fixed by using the $C_1$ .

Comment: @blackcat my bad, thanks. It should be 
$$A(x,t)\ge \frac{\frac14}{\left((1+C_1^2T^2)^2+C_2^2T^2\right)^2}.$$